# Spark UDF: How to write a UDF on each row to extract a specific value in a nested struct?

Tags: java, xml, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I'm using Spark in Java to process XML files. The package spark-xml package from databricks is used to read the xml files into dataframe.

The example xml files are:

```
<RowTag>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>john</name>
    <expenses>
        <travel>
            <details>
                <date>20191203</date>
                <amount>400</amount>
            </details>
        </travel>
    </expenses>
</RowTag>
```

```
<RowTag>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>joe</name>
    <expenses>
        <food>
            <details>
                <date>20191204</date>
                <amount>500</amount>
            </details>
        </food>
    </expenses>
</RowTag>
```

The result spark `Dataset<Row> df` is shown below, each row represents one xml file.

```
+--+------+----------------+
|id| name |expenses        |
+---------+----------------+
|1 | john |[[20191203,400]]|
|2 | joe  |[[20191204,500]]|
+--+------+----------------+
```

`df.printSchema();` shows below:

```
root
|-- id: int(nullable = true)
|-- name: string(nullable = true)
|-- expenses: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- travel: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- details: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- date: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- amount: int (nullable = true)
|    |-- food: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- details: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- date: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- amount: int (nullable = true)
```

The desired output dataframe is like:

```
+--+------+-------------+
|id| name |expenses_date|
+---------+-------------+
|1 | john |20191203     |
|2 | joe  |20191204     |
+--+------+-------------+
```

**And basically I want a generic solution to get the date from the xml with the following structure, in which only the tag `<X>` will differ.**

```
<RowTag>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>john</name>
    <expenses>
        **<X>**
            <details>
                <date>20191203</date>
                <amount>400</amount>
            </details>
        **</X>**
    </expenses>
</RowTag>
```

**What I have tried:**

```
spark.udf().register("getDate",(UDF1 <Row, String>) (Row row) -> {
            return row.getStruct(0).getStruct(0).getAs("date").toString();
        }, DataTypes.StringType);

df.select(callUDF("getDate",df.col("expenses")).as("expenses_date")).show();
```

But it didn't work, because row.getStruct(0) routes to `<travel>`, but for row joe, there's no `<travel>` tag under `<expenses>`, so it returned a `java.lang.NullPointerException`. What I want is a generic solution that for each row, it can auto-get the next tag name, e.g. `row.getStruct(0)` routes to `<travel>` for row john and to `<food>` for row joe.

So my question is: how should I reformulate my UDF to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!! :)

Comment: If you mention that what all things you have tried so far would be helpful. So that your code/tries can be improved or something like that.

Comment: @VarunJain Thanks! Will do it now.

Answer (score 1):

The [spark-xml](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml) package allows you to access nested fields directly in the select expression. Why are you looking for UDF?

```
df.selectExpr("id", "name", "COALESCE(`expenses`.`food`.`details`.`date`, `expenses`.`travel`.`details`.`date`) AS expenses_date" ).show()
```

Output:

```
+---+----+-------------+
| id|name|expenses_date|
+---+----+-------------+
|  1|john|     20191203|
|  2| joe|     20191204|
+---+----+-------------+
```

**EDIT**

If the only tag which is changing is the one after `expenses` struct then you can search for all the fields under `expenses` and then `coalesce` the columns : `expenses.X.details.date`. Something like this in Spark :

```
val expenses_fields = df.select(col("expenses.*")).columns
val date_cols = expenses_fields.map(f => col(s"`expenses`.`$f`.`details`.`date`"))

df.select(col("id"), col("name"), coalesce(date_cols: _*).alias("expenses_date")).show()
```

Still, you don't need using UDF!

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. Sorry that I didn't make it clear. Because I have to deal with the case that I don't know what's coming next under tag <expenses>, it could be <food> <travel> or any other tag names, in this case, I need a UDF function (or any other possible way) to generalize the solution for this part.

Comment: Thanks! Is that possible to translate this into Java? I've tried the solution, and the .columns function returns a string[], with which I cannot use map function...

Comment: In Java 8 you can also use map. Haven't tried it by something like this : `Arrays.stream(expenses_fields).map(f -> col(s"`expenses`.`$f`.`details`.`date`")).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: I have tried this as well, but the collect function will return a List in Java instead of a spark columns...

Comment: This will actually return `List<Column> `. What do you mean by "_List in Java instead of a spark columns_"?

Comment: I mean, do I have to convert the `List<Column>` to `Dataset<Row>` in order to use the `coalesce` function? If so, in the case of this kind of conversion involved, is this approach still faster than UDF? I'm new to Spark, so I'm not totally clear with the underlying concepts, to my understanding, it should be faster when the solution stays with spark functions or UDFs. Please correct me if I'm wrong, thanks!

Comment: No, `df.select` expects a list of columns, not rows! I use Spark mostly with Scala and Python so I gave you the solution in Scala. But I don't think it's difficult to make it in Java. There are 2 steps : (1) create list of columns (if you do not how to do it with map you can do it with for loop) and (2) make a `coalesce` of those columns and select (something like this `coalesce(JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(columns))`). good luck